# What is the $n$-th sequence element for the generating function $\frac{1}{(1-ax)^2}$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

for e.g. for $\frac{1}{(1-ax)} = a^n$
or for       $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = n+1$

generating function = $\frac{1}{(1-ax)^2}$

Comment: You are looking at the derivative of $1/(1-ax)$ with respect to $x$, divided by $a$. Hence the $x^n$ term in this series is...

Comment: (-2)/(1-ax)^2 ?

Comment: Hmmm... The $x^n$ term in a series ought to be $a_nx^n$ for a given coefficient $a_n$, depending (possibly) on $n$ but **not on** $x$. Anyway, in the meantime you received full answers, hence, unless you wish to ask precise questions on specific steps of these, let us stop here.

Answer (score 3):

You give that $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ is the generating function of $a_n=n+1$.  That means that
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)x^k\tag{1}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{1}{(1-ax)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)(ax)^k\tag{2}
$$
Thus, $\frac{1}{(1-ax)^2}$ is the generating function for $a_n=(k+1)a^k.$

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:

Use the general formula for the $k$-th derivative of a power (or establish through induction):

$$\frac{\mathrm d^k}{\mathrm dx^k}\frac1{(1-ax)^2}=\frac{(k+1)!a^k}{(1-ax)^{k+2}}$$

Method 2:

Since $\dfrac1{(1-ax)^2}=\dfrac1{(1-ax)}\cdot\dfrac1{(1-ax)}$, and $\dfrac1{(1-ax)}$ is the generating function for $a^k$, the coefficients of $\dfrac1{(1-ax)^2}$ are given by the autoconvolution of $a^k$; i.e. the sum

$$\sum_{j=0}^k a^j a^{k-j}$$

whose simplification I leave to you.

Answer (score 0):

Another method. By the binomial theorem:
$$
(1 - u)^{-m} = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-m}{k} (-u)^k
$$
Now we have, using Knuth's notation for falling/rising factorials: $m^{\underline{k}} = m (m - 1) \ldots (m - k + 1)$
and $m^{\overline{k}} = m (m + 1) \ldots (m + k - 1)$:
$$
\binom{-m}{k} = \frac{(-m)^{\underline{k}}}{k!}
              = \frac{(-1)^k m^{\overline{k}}}{k!}
              = \frac{(-1)^k (m + k - 1)^{\underline{k}}}{k!}
              = (-1)^k \binom{m + k - 1}{k}
              = (-1)^k \binom{k + m - 1}{m - 1}
$$
Note that this is just a $m - 1$-th degree polynomial in $k$.

So we have:
$$
(1 - u)^{-m} = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{k + m - 1}{m - 1} u^k
$$
The rest of the fun I leave to you.